# I'm trying to make the canvas element move with keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I know this question has been answered like a q2i3648123648 times but I'm trying to make the red square move with the keyboard for some reason the code worked with mouse event but doesn't seem to work with keyboard input
this is the javascript code

```
let canvas;
let canvasContext;

let playerPositionX = 10;
let playerPositionY = 10;
let playerSpeed = 5;
const load = () => {
  canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');


  let framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(() => {
    gameObjects();
  }, 1000 / framesPerSecond);
  // moving the player
  canvas.addEventListener("onkeydown", (e) => {
      if(e.keyCode === 87){
        playerPositionX += playerSpeed;
      }
  });

};
const gameObjects = () => {
  // canvas
  component(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');

  // player
  component(playerPositionX, playerPositionY, 30, 30, 'red');
};

const component = (positionX, positionY, width, height, color) => {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = color;
  canvasContext.fillRect(positionX, positionY, width, height);
};



window.onload = load;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) is a depreciated property. Use [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)

- Separate the keyboard event listener from the control logic.
- Listen to both the key down and key up events and set a flag that a particular key is down.
- In the main loop check that flag and make the movement as needed.
- Use `[requestAnimationFrame][3]` to render.

#### Example

The example below show how to create a keyboard interface. It removes the keyboard auto repeat as a concern. You can stop the input if needed by just setting the `keys.nameOfKey = false;`

```js
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const frameRate = 30;  // must divide into 60 by whole number eg 60,30,20,15,10
var frameCount = 0;

// define keys to listen to
const keys = {
    ArrowUp: false,
    ArrowDown: false,
    ArrowLeft: false,
    ArrowRight: false,
    anykey: false,
};

// sets key to true if key is down
function keyboardEvent(event) {
    if (keys[event.code] !== undefined) {
         keys[event.code] = event.type === "keydown";
         event.preventDefault();
         event.type === "keydown" && (keys.anykey = true);
    }
}

// add key listeners to window
addEventListener("keydown", keyboardEvent);
addEventListener("keyup", keyboardEvent);

// For SO snippet as it will not focus without user click.
canvas.addEventListener("click",() =>  requestAnimationFrame(update), {once: true});
ctx.font = "16px arial";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillText("Click to focus keyboard", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);


const player = {
    x: 0, y: 0, w: 10, h: 10, speed: 5,
    draw() {
        ctx.fillRect(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
    },
    move() {
        if (keys.ArrowUp) { player.y -= player.speed }
        if (keys.ArrowDown) { player.y += player.speed }
        if (keys.ArrowRight) { player.x += player.speed }
        if (keys.ArrowLeft) { player.x -= player.speed }
        if (player.y < 0) { player.y = 0 }
        if (player.y + player.h > canvas.height ) { player.y = canvas.height - player.h }
        if (player.x + player.w > canvas.width ) { player.x = canvas.width - player.w }
        if (player.x < 0) { player.x = 0 }
    }
}

function update(){
     if (frameCount % (60 / frameRate) === 0) {
         ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
         player.move();
         player.draw();
         if (!keys.anykey) {
             ctx.fillText("Arrow keys to move!", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
         }
     }
     frameCount += 1;
     requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

```css
canvas {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thx for the help, I'll need to research some more to get familiar with all of this, but do you recommend using es6 to code canvas and animation or the plain old JS is more than good enough?

Comment: @TarekRoukoz ES6 is far easier to use and a lot less typing, technology advances very quickly (ES6 is 5 years old) so it is always best to keep up with the latest and greatest, lest you fall too far behind.